# English grammar active voice

Tags: grammar, tense, active-voice

I'm learning active and passive voice. I am stuck on this question.

**Q.** *Designer clothes were sold to the masses by Pierre Cardin.*

In the book, the answer is **Pierre Cardin sold designer clothes to the masses.**
But I think the book is wrong and it should be **had sold** instead of **sold**.
Kindly correct me if I'm wrong with the reason.

Comment: I don't understand why you think the perfect tense is better. It's not -- the preterite tense in the active should match that in the passive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this exercise you have to change the voice from passive to active, without changing anything else

The passive voice sentence uses the past tense  "were sold".  This is the past tense because the finite verb "were" is the past tense form of "be".

So the active voice sentence should use the past tense of "sell".  The past tense of sell is "sold".  So the answer is correct.

If the sentence was "Designer clothes *had been sold* to the masses by Pierre Cardin", then the active voice sentence would be "... had sold...".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It means I need to improve my tense first.

Answer (score 0):

Passive Voice (simple past tense): Designer clothes **were sold** to the masses by Pierre Cardin.

Active Voice (simple past tense): Pierre Cardin **sold** designer clothes to the masses.

This is a passive sentence. It has used the simple past tense. So the active voice has to use the simple past tense. We cannot use the past perfect tense here.

Passive Voice (past perfect tense): Designer clothes **had been sold** to the masses by Pierre Cardin.

Active Voice (past perfect tense): Pierre Cardin **had sold** designer clothes to the masses.)